# Google Drive: Remove a folder linked to two locations from one of them

Tags: google-drive

There's a little known feature in the new Google Drive where you can select a folder, click <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and then "add" it to another folder. From there on, the folder is located in both places.

This is useful if you use the selective sync feature. As you can selectively sync only the top-level folders, you can create a dedicated top-level sync folder for your laptop, "add" only those sub-folders you want to sync to your laptop to that sync folder, and then locally select it for syncing on your laptop. You'll be syncing only the stuff you need. I've created such a sync folder for every machine I have, and it works great.

However, if you decide you don't need a specific folder any longer on your laptop, how do you remove it from the laptop's sync folder without deleting the original. From my experimentation, simply deleting the folder in one of the locations, deletes it in both!!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go to the folder online, on the details view you'll see all the locations the folder is linked to.
Click the <kbd>X</kbd> next to the location you want to disconnect, in your case that would be the sync folder you defined.

Answer (score 0):

I had someone linked my files to his drive and I was unable to remove his location as always there was "some server error" message. So I just simply blocked that guy and it was done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

All true, and at first frustrating. However sort of fixable by setting sharing options to "view only" or "comment only" via the "advanced" button in sharing. Admittedly, not a perfect fix.

Comment: What are you saying?  That the user should set his Google Drive to read-only?   The question asks how to delete the “linked” directory without deleting the original.  Is that possible when it’s read-only?